# grpc example helloworld binaries size too big in linux

Tags: c++, grpc-c++

I installed grpc on my ubuntu 22.04
Then I build examples.
I call following:

```
/usr/bin/cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=MinSizeRel -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

and build:

```
/usr/bin/cmake --build /home/user/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/build --target all -j 8
```

In the end I get compiled binaries of basic client-server examples in the build folder.
The size of each of them is bigger than 37MB.
What is the reason?

If I change CMADE_BUILD_TYPE to Release, no difference - size is still 37MB
If I change to Debug, size is more than 40 (that is OK).

Why Release versions of basic grpc example programs are so enormouse in size?

I started this investigation because have same problem with my own project (its size without grps was 10MB, and it is 45MB wtih grpc).

This is cmakelists file from the helloworld

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)

project(HelloWorld C CXX)

include(../cmake/common.cmake)

# Proto file
get_filename_component(hw_proto "../../protos/helloworld.proto" ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(hw_proto_path "${hw_proto}" PATH)

# Generated sources
set(hw_proto_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.pb.cc")
set(hw_proto_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.pb.h")
set(hw_grpc_srcs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.grpc.pb.cc")
set(hw_grpc_hdrs "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloworld.grpc.pb.h")
add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT "${hw_proto_srcs}" "${hw_proto_hdrs}" "${hw_grpc_srcs}" "${hw_grpc_hdrs}"
      COMMAND ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC}
      ARGS --grpc_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        --cpp_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"
        -I "${hw_proto_path}"
        --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc="${_GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN_EXECUTABLE}"
        "${hw_proto}"
      DEPENDS "${hw_proto}")

# Include generated *.pb.h files
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

# hw_grpc_proto
add_library(hw_grpc_proto
  ${hw_grpc_srcs}
  ${hw_grpc_hdrs}
  ${hw_proto_srcs}
  ${hw_proto_hdrs})
target_link_libraries(hw_grpc_proto
  ${_REFLECTION}
  ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}
  ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF})

# Targets greeter_[async_](client|server)
foreach(_target
  greeter_client greeter_server 
  greeter_callback_client greeter_callback_server 
  greeter_async_client greeter_async_client2 greeter_async_server)
  add_executable(${_target} "${_target}.cc")
  target_link_libraries(${_target}
    hw_grpc_proto
    ${_REFLECTION}
    ${_GRPC_GRPCPP}
    ${_PROTOBUF_LIBPROTOBUF})
endforeach()
```

UPD.
My projectg is cross platform, the source is the same.
Under Windows I link statically. The exe file size is 10 times smaller, 4.5MB.
So question to linux binaries gets even harder. Any way to reduce it?

Comment: Does the makefile compile them as static binaries?

Comment: You mean if it links the programs against grpc libs as static? Yes.

Comment: Linux executables will contain debug symbols (if present). On Windows that is a separate file.

Comment: I meant does the makefile that you are building against create a static binary?

Comment: @BoP Do linux executables contain debug symbols when MinSizeRel mode is used?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I placed cmakelists content in the description to answer your question

Comment: @dmitry - I don't know exactly what the different options do, just saying that what is in the executable on Linux can be in separate files on Windows. Would explain some size differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I was able to minimize the size of binaries

1. use `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel` when build grpc.
2. use same when build examples or own projects.
3. `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -s")` to strip the final binary

as a result - the size is 8MB.

Comment: Any other advice for making the binaries smaller? @Dmitry

Comment: No, I have no more. Why?

Comment: Was just investigating how to make binaries smaller, for embedded device.